# Is there an easier way to discover function parameters in MemSQL?

Tags: mysql-connector, singlestore

I need to enumerate all parameters in a MemSQL function. Is there an easier way other than using `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION` and then parsing the definition? For example, when using MySql, I could use

```
connection.GetSchema("Procedure Parameters",
    new string[] { null, database, structureName });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't really a better approach right now.  The `GetSchema` method from your example makes use of a MySQL metadata table that is currently unsupported in MemSQL.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I can submit a feature request to MemSQL team?